# Remove subdomain from string in ruby

Tags: ruby, url, dns, subdomain, uri

I'm looping over a series of URLs and want to clean them up. I have the following code:

```
# Parse url to remove http, path and check format
o_url = URI.parse(node.attributes['href'])

# Remove www
new_url = o_url.host.gsub('www.', '').strip
```

How can I extend this to remove the subdomains that exist in some URLs?

Answer (score 30):

I just wrote a library to do this called Domainatrix. You can find it here: http://github.com/pauldix/domainatrix

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'domainatrix'

url = Domainatrix.parse("http://www.pauldix.net")
url.public_suffix       # => "net"
url.domain    # => "pauldix"
url.canonical # => "net.pauldix"

url = Domainatrix.parse("http://foo.bar.pauldix.co.uk/asdf.html?q=arg")
url.public_suffix       # => "co.uk"
url.domain    # => "pauldix"
url.subdomain # => "foo.bar"
url.path      # => "/asdf.html?q=arg"
url.canonical # => "uk.co.pauldix.bar.foo/asdf.html?q=arg"
```

Comment: This ruby gem references the Mozilla data file at publicsuffix.org.

Comment: Works better than URI, in my experience, for instance in Youtube videos URI removes the ?v=******** field leaving only /watch, whereas Domainatrix works perfectly

Comment: Since this gem hasn't received any updates, see @DarrenCheng's for a more up to date gem: https://github.com/weppos/publicsuffix-ruby

Answer (score 9):

For posterity, here's an update from Oct 2014:

I was looking for a more up-to-date dependency to rely on and found the public_suffix gem ([RubyGems](https://rubygems.org/gems/public_suffix)) ([GitHub](https://github.com/weppos/publicsuffix-ruby)). It's being actively maintained and handles all the top-level domain and nested-subdomain issues by maintaining a list of the known public suffixes.

In combination with URI.parse for stripping protocol and paths, it works really well:

```
❯❯❯ 2.1.2 ❯ PublicSuffix.parse(URI.parse('https://subdomain.google.co.uk/path/on/path').host).domain
=> "google.co.uk"
```

Comment: PublicSuffix was already an included gem in my project as a dependency for another gem.  This was a very handy solution since it was already available.

Answer (score 7):

This is a tricky issue. Some top-level domains do not accept registrations at the second level.

Compare `example.com` and `example.co.uk`. If you would simply strip everything except the last two domains, you would end up with `example.com`, and *`co.uk`*, which can never be the intention.

Firefox solves this by filtering by *effective top-level domain*, and they maintain a list of [all these domains](http://mxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/netwerk/dns/effective_tld_names.dat?raw=1). More information at [publicsuffix.org](http://publicsuffix.org/).

You can use this list filter out everything except the domain *right* next to the effective TLD. I don't know of any Ruby library that does this, but it would be a great idea to release one!

*Update*: there are [C, Perl and PHP libraries](http://www.dkim-reputation.org/regdom-libs/) that do this. Given the C version, you could create a Ruby extension. Alternatively, you could port the code to Ruby.

Answer (score 4):

The regular expression you'll need here can be a bit tricky, because, hostnames can be infinitely complex -- you could have multiple subdomains (ie. foo.bar.baz.com), or the top level domain (TLD) can have multiple parts (ie. www.baz.co.uk).

Ready for a complex regular expression? :)

```
re = /^(?:(?>[a-z0-9-]*\.)+?|)([a-z0-9-]+\.(?>[a-z]*(?>\.[a-z]{2})?))$/i
new_url = o_url.host.gsub(re, '\1').strip
```

Let's break this into two sections. `^(?:(?>[a-z0-9-]*\.)+?|)` will collect subdomains, by matching one or more groups of characters followed by a dot (greedily, so that all subdomains are matched here). The empty alternation is needed in the case of no subdomain (such as foo.com). `([a-z0-9-]+\.(?>[a-z]*(?>\.[a-z]{2})?))$` will collect the actual hostname and the TLD. It allows either for a one-part TLD (like .info, .com or .museum), or a two part TLD where the second part is two characters (like .oh.us or .org.uk).

I tested this expression on the following samples:

```
foo.com => foo.com
www.foo.com => foo.com
bar.foo.com => foo.com
www.foo.ca => foo.ca
www.foo.co.uk => foo.co.uk
a.b.c.d.e.foo.com => foo.com
a.b.c.d.e.foo.co.uk => foo.co.uk
```

Note that this regex will not properly match hostnames that have more than two "parts" to the TLD!

Comment: This regex breaks if you have a TLD with just two letters. For example: `a.b.bigsense.io` should give me `bigsense.io`, but instead it gives me `b.bigsense.io`

Answer (score 2):

Something like:

```
def remove_subdomain(host)
    # Not complete. Add all root domain to regexp
    host.sub(/.*?([^.]+(\.com|\.co\.uk|\.uk|\.nl))$/, "\\1")
end

puts remove_subdomain("www.example.com") # -> example.com
puts remove_subdomain("www.company.co.uk") # -> company.co.uk
puts remove_subdomain("www.sub.domain.nl") # -> domain.nl
```

You still need to add all (root) domains you consider root domain. So '.uk' might be the root domain, but you probably want to keep the host just before the '.co.uk' part.

Answer (score 1):

Detecting the subdomain of a URL is non-trivial to do in a general sense - it's easy if you just consider the basic ones, but once you get into international territory this becomes tricky.

**Edit**: Consider stuff like http://mylocalschool.k12.oh.us et al.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just strip the .com or .co.uk and then split on '.' and get the last element?

```
some_url.host.sub(/(\.co\.uk|\.[^.]*)$/).split('.')[-1] + $1
```

Have to say it feels hacky. Are there any other domains like .co.uk?

Answer (score 0):

I've wrestled with this a lot in writing various and sundry crawlers and scrapers over the years.  My favorite gem for solving this is FuzzyUrl by Pete Gamache: https://github.com/gamache/fuzzyurl . Its available for Ruby, JavaScript and Elixir.