# How to parse a URL and extract the required substring

Tags: ruby, parsing

Say I have a string like this: `"http://something.example.com/directory/"`

What I want to do is to parse this string, and extract the `"something"` from the string.

The first step, is to obviously check to make sure that the string contains `"http://"` - otherwise, it should ignore the string.

But, how do I then just extract the `"something"` in that string? Assume that all the strings that this will be evaluating will have a similar structure (i.e. I am trying to extract the subdomain of the URL - if the string being examined is indeed a valid URL - where valid is starts with `"http://"`).

Thanks.

P.S. I know how to check the first part, i.e. I can just simply split the string at the `"http://"` but that doesn't solve the full problem because that will produce `"http://something.example.com/directory/"`. All I want is the `"something"`, nothing else.

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/ruby.html

Comment: @durron597: Don't hammer everything with regexen. URL is a well defined object, treated million times both in Ruby standard library and in million other gems. If I was an expert, I would answer.

Comment: What's with all the downvotes? Don't get it.

Comment: What if you have something lik `http://a.b.c.d/directory`, more than 2 dots in the host ?

Comment: The downvotes are probably because there are a number of questions similar to this one. You can find out how to get the host from a URL, then find the first element of a `'.'` delimited string.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I'd do it this way:

```
require 'uri'

uri = URI.parse('http://something.example.com/directory/')
uri.host.split('.').first
=> "something"
```

[URI](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.7.0/libdoc/uri/rdoc/URI.html) is built into Ruby. It's not the most full-featured but it's plenty capable of doing this task for most URLs. If you have [IRIs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalized_Resource_Identifier) then look at [Addressable::URI](https://github.com/sporkmonger/addressable).

Comment: I love this. Nice, elegant and isn't expensive. Thanks!

Comment: And it doesn't require us to maintain any regex.

Comment: I think it won't work if the string has colon( : )
eg:  URI.parse('abc123')

Comment: @RamKumar First, read the [URI RFC](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986) to see what it says about the use of colons, then provide a more usable test string in a separate question if you still can't get it to work.

Answer (score 9):

You could use URI like

```
uri = URI.parse("http://something.example.com/directory/")
puts uri.host
# "something.example.com"
```

and you could then just work on the host.
Or there is a gem [`domainatrix`](https://github.com/pauldix/domainatrix) from [Remove subdomain from string in ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/983158/remove-subdomain-from-string-in-ruby)

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'domainatrix'

url = Domainatrix.parse("http://foo.bar.pauldix.co.uk/asdf.html?q=arg")
url.public_suffix       # => "co.uk"
url.domain              # => "pauldix"
url.subdomain           # => "foo.bar"
url.path                # => "/asdf.html?q=arg"
url.canonical           # => "uk.co.pauldix.bar.foo/asdf.html?q=arg"
```

and you could just take the subdomain.

Comment: I think this is a good overall solution for anyone that wants to parse all sorts of URLs. In my case, though, I just need to parse a specific format of URL - which is `foo.bar/somedir`.

Comment: @marcamillion That is why I gave you the first alternative as well, which is the same as what the Tin Man answered.

Comment: @oldergod: How well is that dominatrix maintained? Is it mature?

Comment: @BorisStitnicky I never used it and just found it out today. I don't know.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can use regular expressions.
Something like `/http:\/\/([^\.]+)/`, that is, the first group of non '.' letters after `http`.

Check out http://rubular.com/. You can test your regular expressions against a set of tests too, it's great for learning this tool.

Comment: I started off doing this, but it got pretty messy pretty quickly.

Answer (score 2):

with URI.parse you can get:

```rb
require "uri"

uri = URI.parse("http://localhost:3000")
uri.scheme # http
uri.host # localhost
uri.port # 3000
```